# Enable radio buttons when value in textfield > than x

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to enable a set of radio buttons when the number in a textfield is greater or equal to 150

So far I have this:

```
if ($('#amount').val() > '149' ) {
  $( '#radioterm1' ).removeAttr( "disabled" );
  $( '#radioterm2' ).removeAttr( "disabled" );
  $( '#radioterm3' ).removeAttr( "disabled" );
}
```

But this enables the radio buttons for any number that is greater than 1, do I have to do something with the textfield first before I can check the value of the number ?

Comment: use `parseInt` to convert value to int and compare with `149` (not the string `'149'`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing strings. Use an integer:

```
if (parseInt($('#amount').val(), 10) > 149) {
    $('#radioterm1, #radioterm2, #radioterm3').removeProp('disabled');
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you that works, could you tell me what the `10` does ? I will accept your answer in 11 minutes.

Comment: The `10` tells `parseInt()` what base is being parsed (base 10/decimal in this case). See [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) for details.